# How to listen for when WkWebkiew has finished loading page?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I've tried implementing other code on stackoverflow with no  luck. I'm evaluating javascript in a WKWeview, and would like to listen for when the content has fully loaded in order to execute statements on the loaded page.

Javascript: (isn't executing func webView)

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("_formHist.submit();", completionHandler: nil)
```

Code I've tried using so far: (only works on some pages)

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
    didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    //insert code
    }
```

I'm new to iOS development, so please explain answers in depth if you can!

Comment: you can observe `#keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is `_formHist` defined??

If this isn't defined as a javascript object already, it won't work.

Apart from that, the page may not be fully loaded at the time the code is executed so you may need to listen to an event that is triggered when the page is fully loaded

If you refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery) it tells you that you can determine when the page has fully loaded using the following method

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

So for your case, you just need to use this event listener

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { _formHist.submit(); });", completionHandler: nil)
```

Give that a try and see if it works

Comment: I don't believe it worked. _formHist is an onclick event to an input on a website. The problem is that after submitting _formHist, my above function isn't being triggered.

Comment: This isn't making much sense. for this `_formHist.submit();` to work, `_formHist` would have to be a JS object that references the form DOM element in the HTML, but you haven't shown any code how _formHist is being assigned. first thing I would do if I was you is use a normal, desktop browser and use JS in the debug console to submit the form. then when you have that fully working, then put the *exact* same code into the evaluate javascript method inside the DOMContentLoaded event listener callback

Comment: _formHist.submit(); worked correctly in browser. Just incase my original problem isn't clear, its my following code that is executed to early(providing it here incase it helps):                 webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML",
                                           completionHandler: {(innerHTML, error) in
                                    do  {
                                                let transactionResponse = try TransactionResponse(innerHTML)
                                            }catch{}})

if i add a wait, it works

Comment: `var _divHist = $('divHist');
 var _mnuPlan = $('mnuPlan');
 var _formHist = new AJAXForm( 'svcHistForm', function HistoryDisplay( ajax )
 {
  if ( ajax != null )
  {
   _divHist.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
   window.location = '#viewHist';
  }
  else
   alert( 'Request failed' );
 } );
 function QuickHistory( planID )
 {
  if ( _mnuPlan.value == planID )
  {
   // plan already selected
   window.location = '#top';
   return;
  }
  _mnuPlan.value = planID;
  if ( _mnuPlan.value == planID )
   _formHist.submit();
  else
window.location = '#top';
 }`

Comment: you didn't mention you was using jQuery and didn't show all this code in the question. so is this code what you are passing through evaluate javascript? or is this a script on the webpage?

Comment: this is a script on the website. I didn't know the problem centered around my specific html, my apologies for not including it.

Comment: is this code within a function on the website? you might be able to just call it?

Comment: For me, this approach worked only after adding the event listener to the 'window' object instead of the 'document' object.
webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { doSomething(); });", completionHandler: nil)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to make it much advanced and simple at the same time, so you can show the estimation progress for the user and sure then you can detect that everything was loaded and finished so you can do whatever you want. here's how you can do it:

```
webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
            print(Float(webView.estimatedProgress))
            //Do whatever you want when finished
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, however the function was never called after my above javascript: webView.evaluateJavaScript("_formHist.submit();", completionHandler: nil)

Comment: what is the _formHist??

Comment: _formHist brings the browser to the next page.

html: <input type="button" value="View History" onclick="_formHist.submit(); return false">

Comment: `var _divHist = $('divHist');
 var _mnuPlan = $('mnuPlan');
 var _formHist = new AJAXForm( 'svcHistForm', function HistoryDisplay( ajax )
 {
  if ( ajax != null )
  {
   _divHist.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
   window.location = '#viewHist';
  }
  else
   alert( 'Request failed' );
 } );
 function QuickHistory( planID )
 {
  if ( _mnuPlan.value == planID )
  {
   // plan already selected
   window.location = '#top';
   return;
  }
  _mnuPlan.value = planID;
  if ( _mnuPlan.value == planID )
   _formHist.submit();
  else
   window.location = '#top';
 }`